# How to get text in a NSString that is in between two characters/words?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsstring

I'm trying to fetch a value from a NSString that is between two specific words/characters. Here is the NSString that I'm working with:Name

```
<div id="stat-2">33</div>
<div id="stat-1">Age</div>
<div id="stat-2">28</div>
<div id="stat-1">Location</div>
<div id="stat-2">190.54.5</div>
<div id="stat-1">Lot</div>
<div id="row" style="width:80.4px">                </div>
```

I'm trying to extract the style value which is in this example is width:80.4px How can this be done? I don't think trimming would work so I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `-componentsSeparatedByString:` and `-floatValue`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an XML parser. You could use `NSXMLParser` or any other parser of your choice.

Here's a comparison between xml parsers:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 1):

XML parser if input is XHTML. Regular expressions otherwise (take a look at `NSRegularExpression`).